# How to give an alert if two selected option values are equal in html jquery?

Tags: html, jquery, freemarker

I am trying to block selecting same input values in html.
I tried lots of jquery functions and including this,

```
    $("#targetLanguage").change(function() {
    var a = $("#sourceLanguage").val();
    var b = $(this).val(); 
    if(a === b) {          
        alert(a + ' matches ' + b);
    }
});
```

I think this code should work, however does not do anything. How can I block selecting same input on second select box.

```
<div class="align-items-baseline d-flex flex-column form-group">
   <label for="sourceLanguage"><@spring.message "sourceLanguage"/></label>
   <select id="sourceLanguage" name="sourceLanguage" class="form-control" required>
       <option value="" selected disabled><@spring.message 'selectSourceLanguage' /></option>
          <#list languageList as language>
             <option value="${language.getLanguageCode()}" data-error="<@spring.message "selectSourceLanguage" />"> ${language.languageCode}</option></#list>
     </select>
</div>
    
<div class="align-items-baseline d-flex flex-column form-group">
    <label for="targetLanguage"><@spring.message "targetLanguage"/></label>
    <select id="targetLanguage" name="targetLanguage" class="form-control" data-delayy="1000" required>
        <option value="" selected disabled><@spring.message 'selectTargetLanguage' </option>
            <#list languageList as language>
                <option  value="${language.getLanguageCode()}" data-error="<@spring.message "selectTargetLanguage"/>">${language.languageCode}</option></#list>
     </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you debug? Does change get called? Did you check the values? Are they what you expect?

Comment: I'am not sure what you want to solve with this excerpt code `$("#sourceLanguage").val()` `$(this).val()`

Comment: Please check the *rendered* HTML and include the **rendered HTML** here.  I started to convert your code to a snippet but had too many @spring conditions - especially around generating options where, in the 2nd `select` you have `<@spring.message 'selectTargetLanguage' </option>` - which won't be creating valid HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Try this

### html

```
<div class="align-items-baseline d-flex flex-column form-group">
   <label for="sourceLanguage"><@spring.message "sourceLanguage"/></label>
   <select id="sourceLanguage" name="sourceLanguage" class="form-control" onchage="check_values()" required>
       <option value="" selected disabled><@spring.message 'selectSourceLanguage' /></option>
          <#list languageList as language>
             <option value="${language.getLanguageCode()}" data-error="<@spring.message "selectSourceLanguage" />"> ${language.languageCode}</option></#list>
     </select>
</div>
    
<div class="align-items-baseline d-flex flex-column form-group">
    <label for="targetLanguage"><@spring.message "targetLanguage"/></label>
    <select id="targetLanguage" name="targetLanguage" class="form-control" data-delayy="1000" onchage="check_values()" required>
        <option value="" selected disabled><@spring.message 'selectTargetLanguage' </option>
            <#list languageList as language>
                <option  value="${language.getLanguageCode()}" data-error="<@spring.message "selectTargetLanguage"/>">${language.languageCode}</option></#list>
     </select>
</div>
```

#### Javascript

```
function check_values() 
{
    var sourceLanguage = $("#sourceLanguage").val();
    var targetLanguage = $("#targetLanguage").val();
   
    if(sourceLanguage == targetLanguage) 
   {
     alert(sourceLanguage + " matches "+ targetLanguage);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the disabled attribute from your options

```js
$("#targetLanguage").change(function() {
    var a = $("#sourceLanguage").val();
    var b = $(this).val(); 
    if(a === b) {          
        alert(a + ' matches ' + b);
    }
    console.log('a = '+ a);
    console.log('b = '+ b);
    console.log(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="align-items-baseline d-flex flex-column form-group">
   <label for="sourceLanguage"><@spring.message "sourceLanguage"/></label>
   <select id="sourceLanguage" name="sourceLanguage" class="form-control" required>
       <option value="" selected ><@spring.message 'selectSourceLanguage' /></option>
          <#list languageList as language>
             <option value="${language.getLanguageCode()}" data-error="<@spring.message "selectSourceLanguage" />"> ${language.languageCode}</option></#list>
     </select>
</div>
    
<div class="align-items-baseline d-flex flex-column form-group">
    <label for="targetLanguage"><@spring.message "targetLanguage"/></label>
    <select id="targetLanguage" name="targetLanguage" class="form-control" data-delayy="1000" required>
        <option value="" selected ><@spring.message 'selectTargetLanguage' </option>
            <#list languageList as language>
                <option  value="${language.getLanguageCode()}" data-error="<@spring.message "selectTargetLanguage"/>">${language.languageCode}</option></#list>
     </select>
</div>
```